# Find a file when you know only a part of the name

Tags: php, file

I want to assign the path to a file to a variable, but I know only a part of the file's name. Can I do something like:

```
    $path  = the exact path to the correct folder where the file is;
    $templ = the part of the filename I know for sure;
    $fileExt = the extension of the file (I know it);

    $file = $path . "/" . glob( "*" . $templ . $fileExt );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The problem was that no file was found matching my criteria and an empty array was returned. The solution was to add the path to the file inside the `glob()` function, just like @mnv so helpfully suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write filename with path inside `glob()` and pay attention what result is array of file names:

```
$files = glob($path . "/" .  "*" . $templ . $fileExt );
echo $file[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I doubt it, since your glob is not even pointing at the correct path (that is unless the php file is in the directory you're searching for). So try this instead

```
$file = glob($path . "/" . "*" . $templ . $fileExt );
```

Also, between your $templ and $fileExt, is there a dot there (an actual character/string dot not the joining php dot)?

Comment: Yes, there is a dot in $fileExt, the problem was exactly that I had to include the whole path inside the glob() function